# Why is my XLST variable not showing the correct value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Why is my XLST variable not showing the correct value?

I create a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="name" >
    <p>aa</p>
    <l>ddd</l>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
```

Expected output:

```
<p>aa</p>
<l>ddd</l>
```

Current output:

```
aaddd
```

Here is my code:
http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHV

Comment: Try using `xsl:copy-of` instead...

Comment: pls share the code in online tool ,.here http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHV

Comment: not working http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHV/3

Comment: working fine thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:value-of` prints out all (concatenated) **text nodes**, as a string.

Use `<xsl:copy-of select="$name"/>` or even better `<xsl:sequence select="$name"/>`.

The difference is that `sequence` does not create new nodes but uses references to existing nodes, which results in a better performance.